# asp-route-... not passing the value to the OnGet method in razor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

This is my code:

```
...
    <div class="container">
    @if (pager.TotalPages > 0)
    {
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">
            @for (var pge = pager.StartPage; pge <= pager.EndPage; pge++)
            {
                <li class="page-item @(pge == pager.CurrentPage ? "active": "")">
                    <a class="page-link" asp-route-page="@pge"> @pge </a>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    }
</div>

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet(int page = 1)
        {
            TextPosts = (await _textPostRepository.GetAllAsync())
                .Where(x => !x.Tag.TagManagement.IsMeeting)
                .ToList();
            Tags = (await _tagRepository.GetAllAsync())
                .Where(x => !x.TagManagement.IsMeeting)
                .ToList();

            ViewData["Title"] = "Textes";

            InitializePage(page);

            return Page();
        }
```

Do you know why page value is always 1? The OnGet is triggered when the a tag is cliecked but the value is always 1. I'm wondering what is my mistake? Because clearly, page is well written and I do not know what to do more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not , becuase OnGet will get fired on  from submission, I think

```
@functions
{
    string Method1(int page = 1)
    {
       
    }
}

 <div class="container">
    @if (pager.TotalPages > 0)
    {
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">
            @for (var pge = pager.StartPage; pge <= pager.EndPage; pge++)
            {
                <li class="page-item @(pge == pager.CurrentPage ? "active": "")">
                    <a class="page-link"  onclick=Method1(@pge) > @pge </a>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    }
</div>
```

Other option would be to keep the same code and read the query string.

```
@Request.QueryString["page"]
```

Comment: I have done your querystring and it's working, but is it a bad practice to do that? I mean it is reloading the page and I think in React we do not reload all the page when updating data. But I know I'm in Razo for this issuer, so maybe with this language it is the way to do... Let me know.

Comment: @mathdx what u mean ?

Comment: it is not a bad request, ths is how razor pages design is being developed and maintained by microsoft.